# Allocating time by hours in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have records for various activities that has start and end times that could span hours, like 12:00 = 13:30. I need to allocate time to hours so that the time would be allocated as 12:00 - 1 hour, 13:00, 00:30 for that activity. What is the best way to accomplish this?

Here are the create table, inserts and expected result. Let me know if you need anything else. Thanks!

```
CREATE TABLE Z_SCHED_ACTIVITY
(
SCHED_ACTIVITY_ID decimal(38),
STARTTIME timestamp,
ENDTIME timestamp,
ACTIVITY_ID decimal(38),
EMPLOYEE_ID decimal(38),
SHIFT_ID decimal(38)
);
```

INSERTS:

```
INSERT INTO Z_SCHED_ACTIVITY  VALUES (16452556,{ts '2013-04-11 01:00:00.0'},{ts '2013-04-11 02:00:00.0'},-4107,5217,252849);
INSERT INTO Z_SCHED_ACTIVITY  VALUES (16456677,{ts '2013-04-11 05:30:00.0'},{ts '2013-04-11 05:45:00.0'},-4104,1878,249440);
INSERT INTO Z_SCHED_ACTIVITY  VALUES (16457993,{ts '2013-04-11 03:52:00.0'},{ts '2013-04-11 04:07:00.0'},-4104,5217,252849);
INSERT INTO Z_SCHED_ACTIVITY  VALUES (16613742,{ts '2013-04-11 08:00:00.0'},{ts '2013-04-11 09:00:00.0'},-4107,1878,249440);
INSERT INTO Z_SCHED_ACTIVITY  VALUES (16613744,{ts '2013-04-11 10:30:00.0'},{ts '2013-04-11 10:45:00.0'},-4104,1878,249440);
INSERT INTO Z_SCHED_ACTIVITY  VALUES (16613744,{ts '2013-04-10 23:45.00.0'},{ts '2013-04-11 00:45:00.0'},-4104,1878,249440);

EXPECTED RESULT
Shift ID     EmployeeID            hour start                Sched Time          Activity
249440           1878            04/10/2013 23:00:00           15               -4104
249440           1878            04/11/2013 00:00:00           45               -4104
249440           1878            04/11/2013 05:00:00           15               -4104
249440           1878            04/11/2013 08:00:00           60               -4107
249440           1878            04/11/2013 10:00:00           15               -4104
252849           5217            04/11/2013 01:00:00           60               -4107
252849           5217            04/11/2013 03:00:00            8               -4104
252849           5217            04/11/2013 04:00:00            7               -4104
```

Comment: You will need to generate a table with a row for each hour, then inner join it with your activity table.

Answer (score 0):

A useful trick is to generate all the possible hourly periods from your data, and then use that as part of a join, e.g.:

```
select min_start + ((level - 1) / 24) as hour_start,
    min_start + (level / 24) as hour_end
from (
    select trunc(min(starttime), 'HH') as min_start,
        trunc(max(endtime), 'HH') as max_end
    from z_sched_activity
)
connect by level <= ((max_end - min_start) * 24) + 1;

HOUR_START          HOUR_END
------------------- -------------------
04/10/2013 23:00:00 04/11/2013 00:00:00
04/11/2013 00:00:00 04/11/2013 01:00:00
04/11/2013 01:00:00 04/11/2013 02:00:00
04/11/2013 02:00:00 04/11/2013 03:00:00
04/11/2013 03:00:00 04/11/2013 04:00:00
04/11/2013 04:00:00 04/11/2013 05:00:00
04/11/2013 05:00:00 04/11/2013 06:00:00
04/11/2013 06:00:00 04/11/2013 07:00:00
04/11/2013 07:00:00 04/11/2013 08:00:00
04/11/2013 08:00:00 04/11/2013 09:00:00
04/11/2013 09:00:00 04/11/2013 10:00:00
04/11/2013 10:00:00 04/11/2013 11:00:00

12 rows selected.
```

You can join to your base table on matching periods:

```
with hours as (
    select min_start + ((level - 1) / 24) as hour_start,
        min_start + (level / 24) as hour_end
    from (
        select trunc(min(starttime), 'HH') as min_start,
            trunc(max(endtime), 'HH') as max_end
        from z_sched_activity
    )
    connect by level <= ((max_end - min_start) * 24) + 1
)
select h.hour_start, h.hour_end, zsa.sched_activity_id, zsa.starttime,
    zsa.endtime, zsa.activity_id, zsa.employee_id, zsa.shift_id
from hours h
join z_sched_activity zsa
on not (zsa.starttime >= h.hour_end or zsa.endtime < h.hour_start)
order by h.hour_start, zsa.sched_activity_id, zsa.starttime;
```

I won't show the output because it's a bit messy, but it shows all the periods with one or more where they overlap the base data `starttime` and `endtime`.

You can then calculate the amount of time each of those pseudo-records has in the matching period:

```
with hours as (
    select min_start + ((level - 1) / 24) as hour_start,
        min_start + (level / 24) as hour_end
    from (
        select trunc(min(starttime), 'HH') as min_start,
            trunc(max(endtime), 'HH') as max_end
        from z_sched_activity
    )
    connect by level <= ((max_end - min_start) * 24) + 1
)
select zsa.shift_id, zsa.employee_id, h.hour_start,
    (60*24) * (least(h.hour_end, zsa.endtime)
        - greatest(h.hour_start, zsa.starttime)) as sched_time,
    zsa.activity_id
from hours h
join z_sched_activity zsa
on not (zsa.starttime >= h.hour_end or zsa.endtime < h.hour_start)
order by zsa.shift_id, zsa.employee_id, h.hour_start, zsa.sched_activity_id;

  SHIFT_ID EMPLOYEE_ID HOUR_START          SCHED_TIME ACTIVITY_ID
---------- ----------- ------------------- ---------- -----------
    249440        1878 04/10/2013 23:00:00         15       -4104
    249440        1878 04/11/2013 00:00:00         45       -4104
    249440        1878 04/11/2013 05:00:00         15       -4104
    249440        1878 04/11/2013 08:00:00         60       -4107
    249440        1878 04/11/2013 09:00:00          0       -4107
    249440        1878 04/11/2013 10:00:00         15       -4104
    252849        5217 04/11/2013 01:00:00         60       -4107
    252849        5217 04/11/2013 02:00:00          0       -4107
    252849        5217 04/11/2013 03:00:00          8       -4104
    252849        5217 04/11/2013 04:00:00          7       -4104

10 rows selected.
```

The slightly odd thing here is that for a record with `endtime` of `2013-04-11 02:00:00.0`, that endtime is arguably right at the start of the following hour, which gives you the records with `sched_time` of zero. You can exclude them in the `where` clause by repeating the calculation, or wrap this in an outer `select` than removes them, or you can add another join condition so they aren't considered at all:

```
...
from hours h
join z_sched_activity zsa
on not (zsa.starttime >= h.hour_end or zsa.endtime < h.hour_start)
and zsa.endtime != h.hour_start
...

  SHIFT_ID EMPLOYEE_ID HOUR_START          SCHED_TIME ACTIVITY_ID
---------- ----------- ------------------- ---------- -----------
    249440        1878 04/10/2013 23:00:00         15       -4104
    249440        1878 04/11/2013 00:00:00         45       -4104
    249440        1878 04/11/2013 05:00:00         15       -4104
    249440        1878 04/11/2013 08:00:00         60       -4107
    249440        1878 04/11/2013 10:00:00         15       -4104
    252849        5217 04/11/2013 01:00:00         60       -4107
    252849        5217 04/11/2013 03:00:00          8       -4104
    252849        5217 04/11/2013 04:00:00          7       -4104

8 rows selected.
```